# how to get employee details along with deptname based on maximum salary group by deptname

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables Employee and Dept as below

```
EIN | ENAME   | Salary  | DeptID
 1  | Ravi    |   500   | 10
 2  | Krishna |  1000   | 20
 3  | Kiran   |  1500   | 20

DeptID | DeptName
  10   | IT
  20   | Finance
```

I want the output as employees along with Deptname who is getting maximum salary group by dept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option which does not use analytic functions:

```
SELECT e.ENAME,
       COALESCE(d.DeptName, 'NA') AS DeptName,
       t.max_salary
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Dept d
    ON e.DeptID = d.DeptID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DeptID, MAX(SALARY) AS max_salary
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY DeptId
) t
    ON e.DeptID = t.DeptID AND
       e.Salary = t.max_salary
```

Note that in the event that more than one employee should have the maximum salary in a given department, this query would return all ties.  In the absence of further information, this seems reasonable without being able to distinguish one employee from another.

**Update:**

You could also use a `WHERE` clause containing a correlated subquery instead of joining to a (non-correlated) subquery as I gave above.  Here is what that would look like:

```
SELECT e.ENAME,
       COALESCE(d.DeptName, 'NA') AS DeptName,
       e.Salary
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Dept d
    ON e.DeptID = d.DeptID
WHERE e.Salary = (SELECT MAX(t.Salary) FROM Employee t WHERE t.DeptID = e.DeptID)
```

However, I would recommend using the first option as it would probably perform better than the correlated subquery option.

Comment: Missing comma after `DeptName`, sorry.

Comment: is it possible using correlated subquery alone

Comment: i faced this question in interview will it be possible to do using correlated subquery?